# how can i read html table cell in another page using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have html table in another page i wont to read table cells value
page name qut.html

```
    <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" width="240px;" runat="server">

   <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEE" class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">EURUSD</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1.2644</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1.2647</td>

   </tr>

   <tr class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">USDJPY</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">88.62</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">88.65</td>

   </tr>

   <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEE" class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">GBPUSD</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1.5067</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1.5070</td>

   </tr>

   <tr class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">GBPJPY</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">133.54</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">133.62</td>

   </tr>

   <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEE" class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">GOLD</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1209.77</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1210.27</td>

   </tr>

   <tr class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">SILVER</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">18.09</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">18.13</td>

   </tr>

   <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEE" class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">USDCHF</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1.0554</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">1.0557</td>

   </tr>

   <tr class="text">
      <td><img src="img/down.gif" width="12" height="12"></td>
      <td width="85">AUDUSD</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">0.8774</td>
      <td width="55" align="right">0.8778</td>

   </tr>


 </table>
```

Comment: It's hard to see what your question is here. Do you have any code you've written yet to show us?

Do you need to retrieve this other page, and then parse its contents to extract the specific value you need?

Comment: yes i need to retrieve this other page, and then parse its contents to extract the specific value i need like a value in each <td>

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about screen scraping an HTML page from your page?

Here's a screen scraping example using jQuery

http://www.guru.net.nz/blog/2009/06/screen-scraping-with-jquery.html